# Chrome display no text if we continue make it open for 2 3 hours

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome unable to display whole text although many refresh does not help so.

I have faced this problem so many times, initially i thought it may be my PC problem, but i have seen this error occurs when we use Chrome continuously means does not close browser for 2 3 hours. Once if i close browser and re open then everything is okay.

but i can not close all the time bcoz i opened many tabs simultaneouly

Is this **bug** or what??
Please tell me how to solve this??

Sorry for Bad English
Below is print screen of Chrome
[image: Chrome Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a issue with a plugin - have you tried deactivating the plugins you have installed and checking to see if the error still occurs?

You could also try opening an `incognito` window, you can do this by clicking on the spanner in the top right corner of the browser windows and choosing incognito from the menu. This kind of window disables plugins automatically. To quote from Google:

> You've gone incognito. Pages you view in this window won't appear in
>   your browser history or search history, and they won't leave other
>   traces, like cookies, on your computer after you close all open
>   incognito windows. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will
>   be preserved, however.
>
> Going incognito doesn't affect the behavior of other people, servers,
>   or software. Be wary of: Websites that collect or share information
>   about you Internet service providers or employers that track the pages
>   you visit Malicious software that tracks your keystrokes in exchange
>   for free smileys Surveillance by secret agents People standing behind
>   you Learn more about incognito browsing. **Because Google Chrome does
>   not control how extensions handle your personal data, all extensions
>   have been disabled for incognito windows. You can reenable them
>   individually in the extensions manager.**

Comment: which plugin?? i have installed a lot of plugins. do i need to turn off all the plugin??

Comment: All of them, if there is no error once they have been deactivated then reactivate them one at a time until you find the one causing the problem.

Comment: this error occurs not often. :( anyway Thanks for Help

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new idea.